# Pattern for javascript string replacement

Tags: javascript

Does the following look like acceptable code to replace some escaped regex characters?

```
  export function parseString(s: string): string {
    let r : string;
    if ( s[0] === 'r' || s[0] === 'R' ) {
      r = s.substring(1); // no escape
    } else {
      r = s.substring(1, s.length - 1);
      r= r.replace('\\n', '\n');
      r= r.replace('\\r', '\r');
      r= r.replace('\"', '"');
      r= r.replace('\'', '\'');
      r= r.replace('\\a', '\a');
      r= r.replace('\\b', '\b');
      r= r.replace('\\r', '\r');
      r= r.replace('\\t', '\v');
      r= r.replace('\\\\', '\\');
      r= r.replace('\\?', '?');
      r= r.replace('\\`', '\`');
      const reg = /\\x../gi;
      const regReseult = r.matchAll(reg);
      let iter = regReseult.next();
      while (!iter.done) {
        r=r.replace(iter.value[0], escape_hex(iter.value[0]));
        iter = regReseult.next();
      }
    }

    return r;
  }

  function escape_hex( s: string ) : string {
    let ss= s.toLowerCase();
    if ( ss[0]!== '\\' || ss[1]!== 'x') {
      throw new Error('Invalid hexadecimal escape sequence');
    }
    if ( ss.length !== 4) {
      throw new Error('Invalid hexadecimal escape sequence');
    }
    const reg = /[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/i;
    if ( ss.match(reg) === null ) {
      throw new Error('Invalid hexadecimal escape sequence');
    }
    ss= ss.replace('\\x', '0x');

    return String.fromCharCode(_parseInt(ss));
  }
```

Or, would a better pattern be to capture the various cases as a single regex such as `` \\[nr"'abrt\\?`] `` and then do a substitution based on the capture char? What might be the cleanest way to write the above function?

---

The goal of the above function is to parse a literal string as defined in [BigQuery string-literals](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#string_and_bytes_literals), which may accept a string in various forms such as `"hello"`, `'hello'`, and `r'hello\nthere'`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the specifcation clearly. Can you share a few input/outputs? Why are we taking substrings? Is this browser or Node code, or environment agnostic?

Comment: @ggorlen I added some details here. This is a function that receives a token from a lexer and should normalize it to a "normal string". It should be env-agnostic, but for now I'm running it in node.

Comment: `replace` only replaces the first occurrence of the pattern if the pattern is a string. Are you sure this is working as you'd expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can refactor code this way to avoid these many lines of replace statements like this,

```
const replaceWith = {
    '\\n': '\n',
    '\\r': '\r',
    '\"' : '\''
}; // you can always add more replacement here

for (const key in replaceWith) {
   r = r.replace(key, replaceWith[key]);
}
```